# jQuery Mobile listview swiperight event

Tags: jquery-mobile, webmatrix

I am trying to implement the swiperight event in a jQuery Mobile Web Page (vegPizzas.html) that displays a Veg pizza category in a collapsible listview. The list items are properly displaying the image, name, and price of pizzas in that category. When I swipe right, it is properly handling the swiperight event to display the ingredients. The page is working fine when launched directly in WebMatrix. However, when I launch the home page and navigate to the vegPizzas.html page, the swiperight event stops working and does not displays the ingredients.

The partial script and  code of the vegPizzas.html is:

```
     <script>
        $("nonvegpizzas.html").live("pageinit", function(event) {

        $("#listitem1").on("swiperight",function(){
          $("#listitem1").html("Chicken, Cheese, Onion.")  
        });   
            . . . .
      <body>
          . . . 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-autodividers="true" >
          <li id=listitem1> 
            <img src="Images/vegpizza1.jpg" alt="Cheesy Delight"/>
             <h3 style='margin-left: 15px'>Cheesy Delight</h3>
           </li>
      . . .
       </ul>
     </body>
```

This page is referred from the main index.html file as:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
   <li><a href="vegpizzas.html">Veg Pizzas</a></li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are using separate html pages, you need to move the scripts in vegPizzas.html inside the div data-role="page" so that the default ajax navigation will pickup the scripts as well as the html. By default, jQM only loads the first data-role="page" div when you navigate to a new html page, everything outside the page is not loaded into your home page.